# how I can set the org-agenda to start my week on monday?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm cant set org-agenda to start a week on other day that isn't sunday.

Comment: What have you tried?  The variable `org-agenda-start-on-weekday` looks appropriate

Comment: yeah but i don't  know where I need to set this, in my init.el or in ogr-agenda buffer with one command?? @ebpa

Comment: There are many methods.  To persist across sessions, do `M-x customize-variable [return] org-agenda-start-on-weekday` or put `(setq org-agenda-start-on-weekday 6) ;; saturday` in your init.el

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42571/org-agenda-date-prompt-mini-calendar-start-week-on-monday

Answer (score 5):

In your emacs startup file -- maybe ~/.emacs -- put

```
(setq org-agenda-start-on-weekday 1)
```

and this will set it to Monday.  It will become active the next time you start emacs.  If you want to activate it immediately put the cursor behind the trailing ')' and type C-x C-e -- evaluate preceding S-expression.

Comment: Note that 0-6 is Sunday-Saturday.

Answer (score 3):

As @ebpa comment set variable set custom variable via: `M-x customize-variable` and then `org-agenda-start-on-weekday` to set the day.

Also you have other methods.