# org agenda date prompt mini calendar start week on monday

Tags: org-agenda

When I schedule an item in org agenda, I get the calendar prompt with a mini-calendar of three month blocks. The first column is set to 'sunday'.

I would like to set the first column to 'monday' as the first day of the week, with saturday and sunday on the far right.

Does anyone know which variable governs this behavior?

Thanx,

Simon

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That would be `calendar-week-start-day`

This should do the trick of setting it to monday:

```
(setq calendar-week-start-day 1)
```

Comment: yep, that worked for me. thank you very much.